# PHP Forloop loops through an array and insert current array item into sql database, only one record inserting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script that gets data from a database, then loops through the results from the SELECT query by using a forloop and has a query that inserts the array data into another datbase. However only the first record gets inserted.

I get no errors

Here is the code.

```
//Get all from job
$getRecords = $connection->prepare("SELECT `CustomerFirstName`,`CustomerLastName`,`CASS_STD_LINE1`,`CASS_STD_LINE2`,`CASS_STD_CITY`,`CASS_STD_STATE`,`CASS_STD_ZIP`,`CustomerCounty`,`CustomerNumber`,`DealNumber`,`TradeIn_1_VIN`,`TradeIn_1_Make`,`TradeIn_1_Model`,`TradeIn_1_Year`,`FrontGross`,`BackGross`,`HoldBackAmount`,`VehicleYear`,`VehicleMake`,`VehicleModel`,`VehicleVIN`,`EntryDate`,`matched`,`notNew` FROM `auth` WHERE `matched` = ?");
$getRecords->execute(array($_POST['jobName']));
$gotRecords = $getRecords->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$getRecords = null;


//Loop Through all records found with matching job name
for($i=0;$i<count($gotRecords); ++$i){
    $rec = $remote->prepare("INSERT INTO `cob_matched_records`(first) VALUES (?)");
    $rec->execute(array($gotRecords[$i]['CustomerFirstName']));

}
```

Comment: you should do this in a single insert statement. not a loop around numerous ones..

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: see **[sql_insert_into_select](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)**. just need a simple `insert into select .. from .. where ..` - and you've already got the `select .. from .. where ..` part

Comment: Is your script doing anything else with `$gotRecords`? You're selecting a lot of fields but only `CustomerFirstName` is used "in" the INSERT statement. And what's this: `$getRecords = null;` _before_ the loop? Can't imagine that the code inserts anything.

Comment: @amdixon : I don't think that will work ([out of the box](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html)) because of `$connection->...`/`$remote->...`

Comment: it does work ( out of the box ). see **[mysql federated limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-limitations.html)**. which indicates `..performing bulk inserts (for example, on a INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... statement) is slower than with other table types ..` - meaning it does work ( just not as fast ). it will still be better to maintain in one query than a master and loop query for no reason. also, you seem to be missing error handling code

Comment: The link to the federated engine was only meant as a hint that it _would be_ possible. But a) it's not enabled by default and b) the script doesn't hint to such a setup but uses two separate connections.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your script is most likely the line

```
$getRecords = null;
```

destroying the array before the code hits your for-loop.
(But that doesn't fit your description "However only the first record gets inserted.". Did you post the actual, unaltered code?)

The point (or one of the points) of prepared statements is that you prepare them once and then execute them multiple times with varying parameters. So, prepare the INSERT statement once before the loop and then execute it within with the current parameter(s):

```
// assuming PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, otherwise error handling is missing....
// you might also be interested in http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php
$stmtSelect = $connection->prepare("SELECT `CustomerFirstName` FROM `auth` WHERE `matched` = ?");
$stmtInsert = $remote->prepare("INSERT INTO `cob_matched_records` (first) VALUES (?)");

$stmtSelect->execute( array($_POST['jobName']) );
foreach( $stmtSelect as $row ) {
    $stmtInsert->execute( array($row['cob_matched_records']) );
}
```